# How to split data into multiple rows and arranging according to the titles defined in the code

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using Python Scrapy to scrape a website I am sorry if this is a noob question because I am new in this I know we could split the data with `.split()` but I dont know where to use it.

Here is my spider

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from ..items import FreelancerItem

class MatchSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'match'
    start_urls = ['http://www.totalcorner.com/match/schedule/20191215/']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = FreelancerItem()
        all_table_cols = response.xpath("//tbody[@class='tbody_match']")
        for col in all_table_cols:
            League=  col.css(".td_league a::text").extract()
            Time= col.css(".match_status_minutes::text").extract()
            Match_status = col.xpath("//span[@class='match_status_minutes']/text").extract()
            Yellow_home = col.css(".yellow_card::text").extract()
            Red_home = col.css(".match_home .red_card::text").extract()
            Home = col.css(".match_home a span::text").extract()
            Score=col.css(".match_goal::text").extract()
            Away = col.css(".match_away a span::text").extract()
            Yellow_away = col.css(".match_away .yellow_card::text").extract()
            Red_away = col.css(".match_away .red_card::text").extract()
            Handicap = col.css(".match_handicap::text").extract()
            Corner= col.css(".match_corner::text").extract()
            Goal_Line=col.css(".total_goals div::text").extract()
            Tips=col.css(".newlabel::text").extract()
            Dangerous_attack= col.css(".match_attach div::text").extract()
            Shots=col.css(".match_shoot div::text").extract()


            items["League"] =League
            items["Time"] = Time
            items["Match_status"] = Match_status
            items["Yellow_home"] = Yellow_home
            items["Red_home"] = Red_home
            items["Home"] = Home
            items["Score"] = Score
            items["Away"] = Away
            items["Yellow_away"] = Yellow_away
            items["Red_away"] = Red_away
            items["Handicap"] = Handicap
            items["Corner"] = Corner
            items["Goal_Line"] = Goal_Line
            items["Tips"] = Tips
            items["Dangerous_attack"] = Dangerous_attack
            items["Shots"] = Shots

            yield items
```

And this is my `items.py`

```
import scrapy

class FreelancerItem(scrapy.Item):
    League=scrapy.Field()
    Time = scrapy.Field()
    Match_status = scrapy.Field()
    Yellow_home = scrapy.Field()
    Red_home = scrapy.Field()
    Home = scrapy.Field()
    Score = scrapy.Field()
    Away = scrapy.Field()
    Yellow_away = scrapy.Field()
    Red_away = scrapy.Field()
    Handicap = scrapy.Field()
    Corner = scrapy.Field()
    Goal_Line = scrapy.Field()
    Tips = scrapy.Field()
    Dangerous_attack = scrapy.Field()
    Shots = scrapy.Field()
```

Also I want to arrange it according to the titles but in the csv output it arranges titles alphabetically.

Please help me learn

Thanks.

Comment: do you want convert the table from https://www.totalcorner.com/match/schedule/20191215/ into csv file ?

Comment: and pls ...can you add what return items ??

Comment: yes i want to convert it into csv. I want to return these items --League, Time yellowcard_home ,redcard_home, Home, Score, Away, yellowcard_away ,redcard_away Handicap, Corner, Goal Line, Tips  Dangerous Attack, Shots

Comment: I am getting output in csv like this Saint Kitts & Nevis Premier League,USA UPSL etc in a single row i want to split them in multiple rows.